# how to return lines with no digits using egrep

Tags: grep

I need to search a file with egrep and return the lines that do not contain digits.  I can't figure out how to do it.  I apologize for the ignorant simplicity of my question.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Show us some sample input...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
egrep -v "[0-9]" yourfile
```

That says suppress (`-v`) all lines with any digits in them.

Comment: Thanks.  That did it.  I looked at the man page but missed the -v option.  Thanks again.